# Give $4$ fruits to $3$ kids

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem**: An apple, a pear, a lemon and a mandarin should be given to Bob, Kate and Jane (we have four objects in total, not infinite number of four kinds). Any kid can get any number of fruit, from $0$ to all the $4$ fruit. How many ways are there to do it?

I do know that the answer is $81$. I've also noticed that it's $3^4$. But I don't understand why we need to find the 4th power of 3 to find the number of ways. There's a problem like 'find the number of 5-digit sequences if each digit is either 0 or 1'. The answer is $2^5$ and *that* I can understand: there are 2 ways to fill each digit. But here it is different. Even we think of 3 kids as 'digits', we have $4^3 \neq 81$.

Comment: As I think you see by now, it's the pieces of fruit that are digits, not the kids.  That's because each piece of fruit needs to be assigned to a unique kid and those assignments are independent of each other, whereas a kid is not necessarily assigned to a unique piece of fruit and one kid's assignment does affect the others' assignments.

Answer (score 4):

Each fruit can be given to one of the three kids, so we can think of this as a 4-"digit" sequence where each "digit" takes a value from {"Bob", "Kate", "Jane"}. Thus, there are 3 possible values for each digit, so the total number is $3^4 = 81$.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time we can say that each kid grabs one or many fruits and the answer is $4^3$. It seems weird to me that the way word our solution defines which number is the base and which is the exponent, and I understand that only one answer is true but I'm still confused.

Comment: @alekscooper How are you getting $4^3$?

Comment: @alekscooper You can't treat the kids as digits because the assignment of fruit to one kid necessarily affects what assignments to other kids remain available.  If you had unlimited supplies of each fruit variety available, you would treat the kids as digits and there would be $16^3$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You don't quite say it, but I'm understanding the problem to mean that each piece of fruit has to go to someone.  If there can be leftover fruit, the answer would be $256$.

The apple can go to any of the four kids.  So can the pear.  So can the lemon.  So can the mandarin.  So you have four completely independent three-way choices, which means that the answer is $3^4=81$.

Another way to look at it is this.  The apple is the units digit of a ternary number.  The pear is the $3$s digit, the lemon is the $9$s digit, and the mandarin is the $27$s digit.  If a piece of fruit goes to Bob, the corresponding digit is $0$.  If it goes to Kate, the corresponding unit is $1$.  If it goes to Jane, the corresponding unit is $2$.  So how many possible four-digit ternary numbers are there?

Comment: >>to mean that each piece of fruit has to go to someone.
That's right.

>>If there can be leftover fruit, the answer would be 256.
How is that, could you please clarify?

UPD: Don't clarify, I got it :))